# Mercado Pago Checkout Pro: al ejecutarlo solo se puede pagar con dinero de Mercado Pago

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago, checkout

Estoy integrando checkout pro de mercado pago atraves de Laravel, cuando se ejecuta no me muestra los metodos de pago disponibles para Colombia, solo muestra pagar con dinero de mercado pago y no e excluido ningun medio de pago, aqui esta el Codigo correspondiente a la configuración de Checkout pro (por seguridad no inclui en esta publicación mi acces Token):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use MercadoPago\SDK;
use MercadoPago\Item;
use MercadoPago\Preference;

class MercadoPagoController extends Controller
{
    public function createPreference()
    {
        // Establecer el Access Token
        SDK::setAccessToken('');

        // Crear una preferencia de objeto
        $preference = new Preference();

        // Crear un ítem
        $item = new Item();
        $item->id = "4567"; 
        $item->title = "Test";
        $item->description = "Test";
        $item->quantity = 1;
        $item->unit_price = 41.000; 
        $item->currency_id = "COP";
        $preference->items = array($item);


        $preference->payment_methods = array(
            "excluded_payment_methods" => array(
           
            ),
            "excluded_payment_types" => array(
             
            ),
            "installments" => 6,
            "default_installments" => 1
        );

        $preference->external_reference = "Teste123";


        $preference->back_urls = array(
            "success" => "http://www.google.com/success",
            "failure" => "http://www.google.com/failure",
            "pending" => "http://www.google.com/pending"
        );

        $preference->auto_return = "approved";

        $preference->save();

        return response()->json(['id' => $preference->id]);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

te está saliendo solamente efectivo porque no especificaste medio de pago.

Revisa la [documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/reference/payments/_payments/post) y vas a ver que además de excluir métodos de pago, podes agregarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para obtener los medios de pagos disponibles [aquí tenes la documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/reference/payment_methods/_payment_methods/get)

Comment: Habia entendido que si implementaba Checkout Pro me mostraria por defecto todos los metodos de pago disponibles para Colombia y podria excluir los que quisiera. O no funciona asi? 

Segun lo que mencionaste entonces deberia de incluir ese parametro payment-_type_id, porque lo estoy agregando y no veo ningun efecto.

Comment: probá abrir el checkout en una pestaña de incognito, porque veo que estas logueado en una cuenta de mercadopago